# How to get user details between two ages from dob without age column mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get details of the user between two ages from date of birth. My conditions are,

1. Calculate the age from DOB
2. Find the user details between two ages

My tables is,

```
id    username    phone    dob
-------------------------------------
1     Jithin     123456    31/12/1990
2     Binoy      235612    12/12/1991
3     Jibin      353453    12/12/1996
```

I have create mysql query as below

```
SELECT username, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age FROM tbl_user WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

But the above code shows an error `the column age not found`. How to fix this problem. Any alternate way to find `age` from `dob` and compare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you can't use an alias right away. Use a subquery around it or repeat the calculation. There is a shorter way to calculate it:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age
from tbl_user 
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) between 20 and 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `subquery`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT  username,
        DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - 
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) AS age 
    FROM tbl_user) sub
WHERE sub.age BETWEEN 20 AND 30;
```

Column `age` from `SELECT` clause is not visible in `WHERE` at the same level. You could either wrap it with subquery or repeat entire expression.